# cross platform development

Tags: cross-platform

I have questions on true cross platform development and if it is possible to use ONE platform to develop software.

I have a few applications that I write that work on OS X, Windows and Linux. They all use native platform toolkits with some shared source across platforms. I have to boot to each platform, checkout, compile, etc.

I have in the past tried GUI toolkits like QT (I bought a commercial license for Win, mac, Linus, but very expensive and paying it year after year became hard). I have tried WxWidgets, development moves slow.

So what I am thinking about is there a way to run a single platform and cross compile for other platforms so I can build my products from a single platform.

I favor OS X, is there a way to write apps for OS X, Windows, Linux from OS X where I just need to test on each platform respectively. I have found information on cross compilers, stub compiling, etc, etc.

Does anyone have any thoughts? Is this even possible? Would someone make a killing creating such a beast?

Comment: I suggest Community Wiki on this one.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463431/what-are-some-good-tools-and-strategies-for-multi-platform-development

Answer (score 8):

In my company, we use the **Mozilla Framework** to develop cross platform dictionary products. These applications are based on the Gecko/Necko Browser and most of the development is done via **Javascript, HTML, CSS, XSL, XUL**,... Of course, our homebrew Search engine had to be cross compiled to the three platforms (with some other code which was first done in JS and then ported to moz' C++ for speed reasons).

In the end, we have a reasonnably cross-platform solution: Our developers mostly work like power web-developers (think client and server side at the same time). Because the Gecko is the same on the three platform, we know it will predictably look and behave the same way (except when there are bugs, but the platform is now quite mature on this point of view).

Our R&D knows how to port slow javascript code to rather quick portable C++ code (you do Mozilla code using the NSPR library, a cross-platform lib). Testing has always to be done on the three platform however, although with time and experience, you get to know what will break where (Font support, Audio support, Flash Support)...

Today, you should probably have a look at **XULRunner** which is really the Mozilla without any real browser interface (*in 2002, we had to dismantle the Mozilla Browser to repaint it in our first product colour*). Of course, it works well for simple applications but if you wish to make OpenGL, 3D Audio and other nifty things, XULRunner will appear too limited.

I believe Blizzard has some cross-platform framework for that kind of thing... :)

Good luck!

Pierre.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to develop applications on a single platform that will be used on many platforms isn't a good approach.  At best you'll make applications which feel alien to users of the platforms that you didn't develop for.

More likely, you'll run into subtle compatibility problems in areas which you never forsaw.  Java is probably the best way to go if you want to go down this route.  Cross compiling will lead to autogenerated code that will be a nightmare to debug and maintain.

Certainly, you may be able to use tools for porting in some cases, but I don't think that this is a problem that you can just provide an automated solution for in general.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to be honest, the only guaranteed way to build an app to be cross platform in one go is to use Java, but it requires a rather large runtime to be installed first.

However, if that's not an option, I would recommend keeping an eye on recent developments in Qt - it is now available (or should be soon) under the LGPL, which presumably means you don't need to pay for it anymore. Using GCC with Qt, I've found, works perfectly when cross-compiling on different platforms, as long as you only use Qt's classes/code/objects and make sure that any non-Qt code you create or use is capable of being compiled cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention any specific programming language (but I'm guessing C or C++ because of the GUI toolkits), so it's kinda hard to give a good answer to what you are actually asking.

If you want "true" cross platform, I would first consider if it is possible to solve your problem using a language that is less platform bound. Python, Java and plenty of others allow you to write on one platform, and run on many.

If you still want to use C/C++, GCC gives you the option of cross-compiling, and if you combine that with QT (which will soon be available under the LGPL) you should be able to get something working.

Answer (score 1):

Java has tried to do the write once, run anywhere. It works well in some situations, but there are too many "unique" things in an OS. GCC provided the ability to cross-compile applications, but you run into the same sort of problems. The code will just have better performance. The RIA approach seems to work, but it doesn't feel like a native application.

Answer (score 1):

Even using a cross platform GUI toolkit will not remove all your cross platform problems. There's more to an app than GUI, after all. Cross compiling will never be able to catch all the issues that a native build will catch, either. If you're going to support multiple platforms, you're going to have to at *least test* on each platform. But hopefully you can perform native builds with all warnings turned on, **in addition to testing**.

Answer (score 1):

In the past few months, I found a few great videos exploring this topic of cross platform development.  I hope you find them useful as well.

**QTCreator**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYiPvM7ZRHA&feature=channel

**FlexBuilder**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_O_xDXRsh3Y&feature=channel

**Mono / MonoDevelop**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6VG_Z0aRek

I've personally had success using Silverlight / MacOS X

- http://screencast.com/t/if8xenkt

**RealBasic**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWipoBeKSRk

Answer (score 1):

For Cross Platform Development you can use Phone Gap, Appcelerator (Titanium), Corona... This all provides a framework based on JavaScript and finally able to run on different platforms.  What I am using is Titanium for Mobile Development which allows us to develop applications with Native Codes....  (which is very good advantage). Phone Gap is giving a web app which is not native in general... This softwares are used for development of cross platform supports... with support on Windows, Linux and Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon my personal experience, I believe you should adopt Java: you will avoid many headaches.

You develop in whatever platform you like and you deploy in all other platforms with no need of compiling for each target platform, as you mentioned.

For example, I develop under linux, I hit "compile" only once and the resulting file is ready to be run anywhere (windows, mac, solaris, z/OS, you name it). A double click will run it on any platform (Java runtime must me installed, but most users have it installed already and if not, it's a matter of downloading, installing, "Next>", "Next>", "OK").

If you choose the "Java Web Start" deployment method, it gets even easier: the user just clicks the launch button on a webpage and the application runs (if the proper JVM is installed according to what specified in the JNLP descriptor) or the user gets redirected to the Java download page (if no suitable JVM is found).

GUI development (with Swing toolkit) is easy and powerful, especially if you use the right tool (i.e. Netbeans IDE).